# Periodic data transfer between HDD and SDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, speed, transfer

While sending a big file from HDD to SDD I realized that the transfer speed from HDD plateaued but receiving speed on SSD shows a periodic behaviour.

[image: Screenshot from my Task Manager]

Is there some hardware/SSD internal software reason behind it ? Is it the resolution of measurement ?

- HDD: ST1000LM049-2GH172
- SSD: WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPNUW-512G-1032

Thanks!

Comment: SSD speeds, even SATA SSDs are significantly faster than HDDs. The sampling period could easily fall into areas where the HDD is reading a block of data but the SSD has take everything the OS has at that particular moment. The HDD will be constantly reading, the SSD will be writing in fast bursts. Those bursts may be much faster than the SSD speed but *on average* will be the same as the HDD speed.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that the read/write speed is order of magnitude higher in SSD but I was interested in the pattern. It looks like data is processed in "chunks" by SSD while HDD is sending it continuously, so are these chunks stored/buffered but something before data is redistributed to SSD's transistors ? Does OS store it in RAM before it gets redistributed ? Why the SSD write speed isn't just 1:1 to HDD read in this case ?
When I copy data on SSD it gives a continuous output (probably because read/write has similar values), so this is related to HDD/SSD speed chokepoint for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely just that the SSD is faster at writing than the HDD is at reading - the average appears to be about the same... nothing to worry about.